# Kali Linux wrong resolution (Nvidia 950m)

Tags: linux, graphics-card, kali-linux

So I'm trying to install Kali Linux on my USB Stick to boot it on my computer. This works perfectly but whenever I boot Kali the resolution is definitly wrong. I made some pictures for you:

[Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA4Iz.jpg)
[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxvbc.jpg)

Some infos about my notebook:

Name: Acer Aspire E 15

Graphic card: Nvidia Geforce gtx 950m graphic card

Ram: 16GB

Processor: Intel i7 2.7 GHz

I seached for a solution in the internet but I couldn't find one. So does anyone else knows this problem or even know how to solve it?

Thank you very much for you help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install nvidia driver first here http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/118290 and then you can change the resolution in nvidia setting application that show after you install that driver